# Heroku app with custom domain doesn't store the user appropiately

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, heroku, cookies

When setting a custom domain on Heroku, my app doesn't store the user appropriately.
(https://www.justlaunched.xyz/)

When I'm trying to make a post or put requests involving the following middleware: `isAuthenticated()` https://github.com/asierbayon/justlaunched/blob/master/middlewares/isAuthenticated.middleware.js

It says that the user is not authenticated when it actually should be.

Example:

1. Login with Metamask
2. Edit profile
3. 401 comes out

When I'm trying to do this on the normal Heroku domain (https://justlaunched.herokuapp.com/), it works fine.

All the code is available publicly at https://github.com/asierbayon/justlaunched

What's working wrong with my application?

Comment: Without a [mre] it's impossible to say.

Comment: Sorry Jon, just edited my post :)

Comment: That's not a MRE.

Comment: "All the code is available publicly…"—that's great, but we're not going to go off-site and dig through your repo on GitHub. Questions here need to be self-contained. Please [edit] the relevant authentication code, any session code, etc. into your question.